# Get redirect location of URL list

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I have a txt file with a list of URLs. I want the redirect locations of all the URLs in that list.
Here is my code:

```
$url_list = "ggurl.txt";


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

foreach (file($url_list) as $url) {

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($ch);

    // line endings is the wonkiest piece of this whole thing
    $out = str_replace("\r", "", $out);

    // only look at the headers
    $headers_end = strpos($out, "\n\n");
    if( $headers_end !== false ) { 
        $out = substr($out, 0, $headers_end);
    }   

    $headers = explode("\n", $out);
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if( substr($header, 0, 10) == "Location: " ) { 
            $target = substr($header, 10);

            echo "[$url] redirects to [$target]<br>";
            $url = $target;
            continue 2;
        }
    }

$url = rtrim($url);

echo $url . "<br>";

}
```

The problem with this code is that it only shows the redirect location of the last URL in the list. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: please give value of '$headers'

Comment: I've just printed $headers and this is what I get (sorry for the lack of structure): see next post.
The ggurl.txt has 3 URLs now. As you can see, the first 2 arrays are empty, only the last is working.

Comment: Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => ) Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily [1] => Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 09:09:44 GMT [2] => Cache-Control: PUBLIC, max-age=900,must-revalidate [3] => Expires: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 09:24:44 GMT [4] => Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=556E7014B5319118D3F31E52741DF0ED; Path=/ms [5] => Location: http://betonccb.be/nl [6] => Content-Language: nl-BE [7] => Content-Length: 0 [8] => Vary: Accept-Encoding [9] => Content-Type: text/html [10] => Set-Cookie: BIGipServerwd-web-be=352393226.20480.0000; path=/ )

Comment: Do you get any output at all for the other URLs in the file? Can you put the exact contents of the ggurl.txt? The code works as is for me, with a quick ggurl.txt I made - though I did have to add: $url = trim($url) on the lime immediately after the foreach loop to pull off the new lines (tested on a linux system).

Comment: Ahh you posted that as I was typing my comment :) If you print the URL at the beginning of the loop are you indeed getting the correct URL with no additional characters?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked! The problem was that it is getting "http://www.url.com " from the txt file, so with a whitespace. When I trim the URL immediately after getting it from the file it works. Although I don't understand why it is getting a whitespace from the file when I can't see them in notepad or notepad++.