# Getting executed URL from CURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a Affiliate URL Like http://track.abc.com/?affid=1234
open this link will go to `http://www.abc.com`

now i want to execute the `http://track.abc.com/?affid=1234` Using CURL
and now how i can Get `http://www.abc.com`
with Curl ?

Comment: Just use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and curl will continue to the redirected page

Answer (score 2):

If you want cURL to follow redirect headers from the responses it receives, you need to set that option with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

You may also want to limit the number of redirects it follows using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
```

So you'd using something similar to this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://track.abc.com/?affid=1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Edit:** Question wasn't exactly clear but from the comment below, if you want to get the  redirect location, you need to get the headers from cURL and parse them for the Location header:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://track.abc.com/?affid=1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

This will give you the headers returned by the server in $data, simply parse through them to get the location header and you'll get your result. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315161/get-redirect-location-of-url-list) shows you how to do that.

Comment: this code results gives all the html code of http://www.abc.com
but i want to store http://www.abc.com in $data

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function that will extract any header from a cURL header response.

```
function getHeader($headerString, $key) {
    preg_match('#\s\b' . $key . '\b:\s.*\s#', $headerString, $header);
    return substr($header[0], strlen($key) + 3, -2);
}
```

In this case, you're looking for the value of the header *Location*. I tested the function by retrieving headers from a TinyURL, that redirects to http://google.se, using cURL.

```
$url = "http://tinyurl.com/dtrkv";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$location = getHeader($data, 'Location');
var_dump($location);
```

Output from the var_dump.

```
string(16) "http://google.se"
```